# Segmentation fault in printf using ctypes

Tags: python, c, python-2.7, segmentation-fault, ctypes

I'm trying to connect some of my python scripts to C functions to increase performance with respect to python code only.
I found the ctypes module and it worked fine for some simple examples but always produces "segmentation fault" if I'm using malloc or printf within the called C-function.
I created a minimum example code that causes the problem on my machine:

foo.c:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void foo(){
    printf("Hello World!");
}
```

foo.py:

```
import ctypes

c_foo = ctypes.CDLL('foo.dll')
c_foo.foo.argtypes = []
c_foo.foo.restype = None

c_foo.foo()
```

I'm still hoping that it's just a stupid mistake of mine but I couldn't find the problem for hours now.
If it helps, I'm using windows on a 64bit machine, anaconda distirbution of python 2.7.13. The command I'm using to compile the C-File ist: "gcc -shared -fPIC -o foo.dll foo.c" (which worked for trivial examples).
Thank you for your time.

EDIT:
I found another (possibly) strange behavior. Until now I only tried to run the python scripts within cygwin. Today I tried it with the windows console (cmd.exe) and was suprised (and happy) that no "segmentation fault" occured but unfortunately the script stops at the very same position as before without any error displayed.
Another thing, the following code works fine, so pritnf in general doesn't seem to be the problem:

```
from ctypes import *
libc = cdll.msvcrt
libc.printf("Hello")
```

Comment: Your function's return type is `void` (`None`), not a `void*` (`ctypes.c_void_p`). Try `c_foo.foo.restype = None` and see if that works. Make sure to use `restype`, not `restypes`, as the latter will have no effect whatsoever.

Comment: It seems to me that your C environment might not be getting initialized.  That means that heap memory is not set up and malloc fails.  I found a claim that the command line must include `-Wl,--out-implib` "iff (==if and only if) the DLL shall be interfaced from some C/C++ compiler other than the MinGW toolchain".  It's not clear to me if that applies here, but you might try it.  Also the GCC docs say that you should name your library with the extension ".dll" if you use the -shared option.

Comment: Thanks both of you. I tried to change the restype (and used the correct syntax "c_foo.foo.restype" without "s"), I even tried Integer (of course I changed the C-Code accordingly) but the problem stays the same.
I changed the code in the startpost accordingly.

I tried "gcc -shared -fPIC -o foo.dll foo.c -Wl,--out-implib". It compiles without any errors and produces an additional file named "--library=gcc_s" but unfortunately the "semgmentation fault" still occurs.
As you can see, I also changed the output's file extension to .dll but that didn't fix the problem either.

Comment: A problem during the compilation concerning references seems reasonable to me, since the problem only occurs when I'm using methods from included header files (e.g. "#include <stdlib.h>" for "malloc" or "#include<stdio.h>" for "printf"). But using functions defined within my own header files works well.